# Is it possible to get data from a website for Azure ML?

Tags: azure, machine-learning

For an experiement I need data from football matches (the results and statistics of both teams before the match, the result of the match, the number of spectactors, the referee etc.). On www.flaschscores.com it is very well summarized. Is it possible to import date from that website into an Azure ML experiement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AzureML` only supports the following [data formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-import-data):

- Plain text (.txt)
- Comma-separated values (CSV) with a header (.csv) or without (.nh.csv)
- Tab-separated values (TSV) with a header (.tsv) or without (.nh.tsv)
- Excel file
- Azure table
- Hive table
- SQL database table
- OData values
- SVMLight data (.svmlight) (see the SVMLight definition for format information)
- Attribute Relation File Format (ARFF) data (.arff) (see the ARFF definition for format information)
- Zip file (.zip)
- R object or workspace file (.RData)

Nevertheless this gives you a lot of versatility, you can use web technologies to web scrape any site and create a csv, or store the data in an `Azure SQL` databases, and you can connect that data source to `AzureMl`.

By itself `AzureML` is not designed to web scrape websites.